# Decrease audio quality

Tags: python

I'm trying to build an 'old radio' with raspberry pi 4 and python 3. I have a button which records my sound as long as I'm holding the button. When I release it, it replays the recorded sound and also plays an other wav file as background noise. My problem is that my voice is too clear and doesn't sound like an 'old radio' with noises and crackling.

I have tried to change `CHUNK` and nothing happened. Changing the `RATE` only makes my sound deeper/higher.

I'm using an USB converter for the microphone and the headset aswell.

Basically, I want to add 'noise' or any effect to my voice that makes it sound like it's from an old radio.

```py
import time
import pyaudio
import wave
import sched
from pygame import mixer
import audiosegment
import numpy as np
from gpiozero import Button

CHUNK = 8192
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 45000
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"
button = Button(2)

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
frames = []


def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    frames.append(in_data)
    return in_data, pyaudio.paContinue



started = False
stream = None
playing = None;


def recorder():
    global started, p, stream, frames, button, playing


    if button.is_pressed and not started and not playing:
        # Start the recording
        try:
            stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                            channels=CHANNELS,
                            rate=RATE,
                            input=True,
                            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
                            stream_callback=callback)

            print("Stream active:", stream.is_active())
            started = True
            print("start Stream")
        except:
            raise

    elif not button.is_pressed and started:
        try:
            started = False
            print("Stop recording")
            stream.stop_stream()
            stream.close()
            wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
            wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
            wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
            wf.setframerate(RATE)
            wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))


            mixer.init()
            mixer.Channel(0).set_volume(0.1)
            tada = mixer.Sound('old_radio.wav')
            channel = tada.play()

            s = audiosegment.from_file(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME)

            main = mixer.Sound(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME)
            channel1 = main.play()
            if 'channel1' in locals() and channel1 is not None:
                while channel1.get_busy():
                    playing = True
                    channel.unpause()
                channel.pause()
                channel.stop()
                channel1.stop()
                playing = False

            frames = []
        except:
            raise

    # Reschedule the recorder function in 100 ms.
    task.enter(0.1, 1, recorder, ())


print("Press and hold the button to begin recording")
print("Release the button to end recording")
task = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
task.enter(0.1, 1, recorder, ())
task.run()
```

Comment: if i understand correctly, you're trying to record two playing audio, to mix them? i'd suggest find some libray to merge two audios directly.

Comment: Related resources [here](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/24082/how-can-i-make-a-section-in-a-song-sound-like-its-coming-from-an-am-radio), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/AudioPost/comments/5gleed/making_a_recording_sound_like_its_from_an_old/), and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/audioengineering/comments/12rqj8/old_timey_radio_effect/)

Comment: No, the other sound is just for background noise. But I also want my voice to be lower quality